# Why cached memory alignment required?

Tags: c, caching, memory, gnu, mips32

I am working on mips32, gcc compiler with micro-mips optimization. Each core has it's own cache memory. Core A os - ThreadX, Core B os - rtos. I wish to pass pointer and size from Core A to Core B.
Let's take a look at the following flow:

```
1. Core A(ThreadX): pass pointer and size to Core B
2. Core B(RTOS): write to pointer size bytes
3. Core B(RTOS): flush(pointer)
4. Core A(ThreadX): pointer cacheInvalidate(pointer)
5. Core A(RTOS): copy from pointer to buffer
```

I worked with unaligned address, seems that it caused some unexpected issues.
After passing aligned address I failed to reproduce the issues.
Do I have to work with an aligned address? Why? What behavior should I expect if I will pass unaligned address?

Comment: This is very much a CPU-architecture specific thing. Please edit your question to add what CPU-architecture you're working on (preferably by adding its tag).

Comment: So was the program in **C** or **not**? In C, the thing is clear. Even calculating misaligned pointer leads to **undefined behaviour**, let alone dereferencing it!

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Yes the program is written in c. May you please supply more information about "undefined behavior" also could you explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't reason at such a low level, if you care about portable C. Look into the assembler code generated by your compiler if you don't (e.g. using `gcc -O -fverbose-asm -S` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)).

If you care about a particular implementation, you should mention it (compiler and version, [optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) flags, operating system, processor and brand). But beware of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), be [scared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108) of UB.

If coding in C: with C99, you need operating system stuff and support, e.g. [pthreads(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html) (which uses [futex(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/futex.7.html)). So read a [pthread tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/). with a C11 conforming implementation (see [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)), you could use [atomic operations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic), and [`<threads.h>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread)

> Do I have to work with an aligned address?

Perhaps yes. Your hardware is accessing aligned data in a different (and quicker and more "atomic") way than non-aligned data. [Cache coherence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_coherence) is specific to a particular processor in its details.